# PHP cuRL - 403 forbidden when trying to access site with authentication

Tags: php, curl

Using PHP cURL I am trying to receive data from a site that requires browser authentication.

[image]

PHP Code:

```
$header = array();
$header[] = 'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("$client_id:$client_secret"); 
$header[] = 'Accept: application/json;odata=verbose';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);

$r = curl_exec($ch);
  if (curl_error($ch) || $r === false) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
  }
  else
  {
    $data = json_decode($r, true);
    print_r($data);
  }
```

However when running the following code I am getting the following output.

[image]

The credentials are correct but I am unable to cuRL the site. Why would this be?

Comment: seems you require a csrf token to login here, you provide no code to retrieve/post one. also, rather than crafting the http basic auth headers yourself, you should probably let curl handle it, set CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH to CURLAUTH_BASIC , and use CURLOPT_USERPWD to set username/password

Comment: but generally, when it `works in the browser, and doesn't work in curl`, the trick is compare the request that curl does, with the request that chrome does, and systematically take away every single difference between the curl-based request and browser-based request, until they're exactly equal, and retrying every step of the way.. FiddlerProxy comes in handy here

Comment: @hanshenrik Thankyou for the response. I guess I'll research on how to add a crsf token via curl. Also FiddlerProxy for some reason doesn't log an entry when I authenticated myself to that site through Chrome.

Comment: what does chrome's devtools "Network" tab say?

Comment: I opened network monitoring on chrome tools. Entered the authentication and hit enter. It just gave me a entry with Status Code:200 OK with Request Headers(empty) and everything else blank

Comment: open a blank tab, open dev tools, go to Network, check "Preserve Log" before going to the website, in that tab. *then* what does the network tab say?